# ASP.NET Web Form not loading stylesheets after windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to create a simple web form with windows authentication. I haven't done anything more than create the project. Like so -

When I hit f5 to view in browser, the pages load, though with no style like so..

[image] 
As far as I'm concerned, it's meant to look like a nice bootstrap file.

Some things I've tried -

Update my web config

```
<location path="Content" allowOverride="true">
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
</system.web>
```

Made sure that the paths are correct (though I haven't touched anything since making the project).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: 
I've created another project - and the only difference between this one and the one above is that there is no authentication. When I load the about page, the style loads as seen below -

Should also mention that this is a Visual Studio 2015 project...

[image]

Comment: What response do you see in console for the stylesheet file request, when the request fails ?

Comment: @Boney I'm getting 404 :(

Comment: If it is 404, it shouldnt be related to Authorization. Could you please show me the code referencing stylesheet file ? 
Also please verify if the file actually exists at the target, in case the code is deployed somewhere.

Comment: There's really no code for me to show you - it's the stuff that's been generated after creating a new project (visual studio 2015). I haven't made any changes myself. If it helps, the code referencing from the Site.Master file is <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />. The files do exists.

Comment: ok. In the rendered HTML(View Source), could you please check the path to which "~/Content/css" gets resolved to. If it is the same path you expected the css file to be present.

Comment: @Boney it's rendering as expected -  <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

Comment: ok and I assume both style sheets are not loading. 
Another qn. Is it hosted in IIS or VS server ?

Comment: Also please try loading a JS or Image file in the page, just to confirm it is an Authentication issue.

Comment: yehp, JS files and images are not loading - looks like it's an auth issue - any ideas of how to fix this?

Comment: ok. Go to IISManager. Select the applicable Site.
Double click Authentication in the list of buttons.
Make sure Anonymous Authentication is Enabled.
Select Anonymous Authentication. Click Edit.
Change "Anonymous User Identity" to "Application Pool Identity".

Comment: Hi Elliot. Did you try changing the IIS settings as i suggested ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. CSS was not loading when I enable Windows authentication.

The error code in iis log was 500 0 1346.

This was resolved after adding the application pool identity to the administrators group. Basically, the application pool identity must have "impersonate a client after authentication" policy. So adding it to a group with this policy should fix.

Article - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asgoyal/2012/08/25/one-thing-you-must-do-when-getting-http-500-0-1346-error/